# My Account display only after login

Tags: magento2, login, customer-account

Want to know how to display "My Account" only after customer LogIn. After LogOut it will again be hidden on the same place. New to Magento 2

thx for help

Answer (score 2):

The `customer_logged_*` layout handles used in M1 were removed in M2. Below is a small plugin using a method similar to what's used in core for adding/removing the "Register" top link in `Magento\Customer\Block\Account\RegisterLink`

> Vendor/Module/Plugin/Link.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Context;

class Link
{
    protected $httpContext;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $context
    ) {
        $this->httpContext = $context;
    }
    public function afterToHtml(\Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link $subject, $result)
    {
        if ($this->httpContext->getValue(Context::CONTEXT_AUTH)) {
            return $result;
        }
        return '';
    }
}
```

> Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Link">
        <plugin name="vendor_module_toplinks_myaccount" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Link" sortOrder="10" />
    </type>
</config>
```